# Allocation of single sharded indexes among multiple nodes

Tags: elasticsearch

I create monthly indexes for my time-based data set. If each index had only 1 shard and I had 2 nodes, how would the indexes be allocated between the two nodes? More precisely, would the shards be balanced between the 2 nodes?

Answer (score 1):

By default Elasticsearch will try to allocate the same number of shards on each node.